# How can I install ivms-4200 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ivms

I stand Ubuntu desktop 14.04 withe WINE. I've installed ivms-4200 by Hikvision and it doesn't work.
Could you tell me how I can install ivms-4200 on Ubuntu?

Regards,

Adam

Answer (score 1):

I linked all the missing libraries (which are included with the download from Hikvision) to `/lib` and it worked for me. `Ubuntu 14.04.3 amd64`